# Calculate distance between two latitude longitude pairs with liquid syntax

Tags: liquid

Im using liquid syntax and have to calculate the distance between two latitude/longitude pairs. This is in order to determine if a coordinate is within the radius of a circle (another coordinate + radius).

Ive haven't found any documentation on liquid syntax having trigonometry functions.

Thanks